# How do I hide y2 axis in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

How do I hide y2 axis (Z axis) in the chart below using drawAxis option in Dygraph? The drawAxis:false option is not working in example snippet below.

I took the following example from http://dygraphs.com/ 's play example and modified to suite my question.

```js
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
  // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
  // The x-values could also be dates, e.g. "2012/03/15"
  "X,Y,Z\n" +
  "1,0,3\n" +
  "2,2,6\n" +
  "3,4,8\n" +
  "4,6,9\n" +
  "5,8,9\n" +
  "6,10,8\n" +
  "7,12,6\n" +
  "8,14,3\n", {
    // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
    legend: 'always',
    animatedZooms: true,
    title: 'dygraphs chart template',
    series: {
      'Z': {
        axis: 'y2'
      }
    },
    axes: {
      y2: {
        drawAxis: false
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
/*
Relevant CSS classes include:

Labels on the X & Y axes:
.dygraph-axis-label
.dygraph-axis-label-x
.dygraph-axis-label-y
.dygraph-axis-label-y2

Chart labels, see http://dygraphs.com/tests/styled-chart-labels.html
.dygraph-title
.dygraph-xlabel
.dygraph-ylabel
.dygraph-y2label

The legend, see http://dygraphs.com/tests/series-highlight.html
.dygraph-legend
*/

.dygraph-title {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<!-- You may set style: "width: ...; height: ..." to size the chart -->
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: That's strange, the [default behavior](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawAxis) for `drawAxis` is *"`true` for `x` and `y`, `false` for `y2`"*.

Comment: I have no clue why this does not work as expected. You could try adding this CSS rule as a *hack* to get the chart to hide the `Z` labels: `.dygraph-axis-label-y2 {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: I [opened an issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/614), regarding this problem, on the Dygraphs Github project page.